# How to pass main app class to a framework

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks

I recently added framework into my project and it works fine however there is implementation that only exists in my app that i need to pass to the framework. I am unsure if this is possible an di would like advice on how to achieve this if its possible.

The expected outcome would be to get an instance of the main app class to the framework such that i can use the functions in the main app in the framework.

Scuedo code :

**In the framework create a protocol :**

```
public protocol FrameworkBridge: class {
    func tapOnClaimToken()
}
```

**In the main Application create a class that confirms to the framework protocol:**

```
 class FrameworkBridgeImplementation: FrameworkBridge {
    func tapOnClaimToken() {
        // call some code which only exists in the main app
    }
}
```

**Another Class in the framework:**

```
 class  AnotherClassIntheFramework {

    var frameworkBridge: FrameworkBridge?

    func performAction {
        frameworkBridge.tapOnClaimToken()
    }
}
```

Comment: What is "the main app class?" If you mean the AppDelegate, you almost certainly should not be passing that to anything (the application delegates job is to provide delegate methods for the UIApplication, not be a dumping ground for global state). But in any case, the answer is going to be "create a protocol in the framework, and pass objects that conform to that protocol to the framework." The details will depend on your specific situation.

Comment: by main app class i mean any class in the app not the appdelegate

Comment: Sounds like a very bad approach. How does the "framework" know what functions are in the class you are passing? You should probably edit your question to explain exactly what you're trying to accomplish - be specific, not *"get some undescribed framework to use some undescribed function"*.

Comment: Your edited code looks exactly correct. I assume somewhere in your application code you have `anotherClassInTheFramework.frameworkBridge = self` or something like that. Looks like you're done. Is there a question here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass an object to a framework, the framework should generally define some protocol that it expects. Then conform your main application type to it, and pass it to the framework.

If the implementation in question is just a single function, it is often easier and better to just pass the function itself as a parameter.

This pattern is very common; it's exactly how you're able to pass your custom UITableViewDelegate implementation to UIKit and allow UIKit to call your methods.

Comment: I have added scuedo code to the best of my understanding of your answer however im not sure how to proceed